# Making a table of results from SystemModelSimulate

Tags: list-manipulation, system-modeler

I am trying to simulate a model in SystemModeler from Mathematica 11.3. I wish to simulate this model for various parameter values and make a table of the output data. To attempt this I do the following:

```
model = SystemModel["rectifier_circuit"]
simulations = 
  Table[
    SystemModelSimulate[model, 0.025, Method -> {"Heun", "StepSize" -> i}], 
    {i, {PowerRange[0.0001, 0.1]}}]
```

When evaluating the above, I get the following error:

> SystemModelSimulate::smss: Value of suboption "StepSize" should be a non-negative number.

Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Try removing the extra set of `{}` around `PowerRange`.

Answer (score 2):

User [b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks)'s comment about removing the extra {} surrounding the PowerRange fixes the issue.

Code is now:

```
simulations = 
 Table[SystemModelSimulate[model, 0.025, 
   Method -> {"Heun", "StepSize" -> i}], {i, PowerRange[0.0001, 0.1]}]
```

and the output is a table of SystemModelSimulationData as desired.